# How to concat some value in the existing value of a xml using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Apologises if duplicate. I want to perform a concat operation on the values of the xml elements.

```
I have xml say Input.xml

<collection>
<one>
   <part>1</part>
</one>
<two>
   <part>2</part>
</two>
<three>
   <part>3</part>
</three>
</collection>
```

I want the output like :

```
<collection>
<one>
   <part>001</part>
</one>
<two>
   <part>002</part>
</two>
<three>
   <part>003</part>
</three>
</collection>
```

how to write xslt for it

Answer (score 0):

Quick hacky XSLT , tested it online it seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction">
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="//part">
            <part>
                <xsl:text>00</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
            </part>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this is a bad solution. (a) dont use leading `//` in matching. (b) removing attributes, comments, and so on is unnecessary and was not asked by threadopener! (c) even if it works, doesn't mean it's usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Your possible solution might be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="part">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '000')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- identity copy -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Format the text in `part` to a 3 digit number format**